# How to get Client device information in asp.net, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, client-hints

I am stuck while fetching client side information of their device, I didn't want to show my server device info to client.

I want whoever visit my site I get their mobile/laptop name, model, OS version, and all other info.

Comment: "and all other info" that's vague.

Comment: ok no need all let me help of above mention please if you know

Comment: (for information I found this Q&A by copying and pasting the exact title of the question here in Google)

Comment: no this is not i already read that

Answer (score 1):

> I want whoever visit my site I get their mobile/laptop name, model, OS version, and all other info.

**You can't** (or rather: you're not meant to be able to).

Modern browsers are now designed to hide that information from web-pages to prevent spying and tracking users. This is also known as "device fingerprinting".

The only information you can get is in the `User-Agent` header, and I note that [ultramodern browsers now no-longer update the `User-Agent` header](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-to-phase-out-user-agent-strings-in-chrome/) and instead provide even less information [through the "Client hints" headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Client_hints).